# Java Axis web service call Transport error: 403 Error: Forbidden

Tags: java, ssl, apache-axis

Have some java code which is calling a web service over SSL. This code functions in one environment, however when it is promoted to a different domain it fails with a 403 error. Has anyone encountered this before, or have any thoughts about what may be causing it?

```
catch org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 403 Error: Forbidden
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:310)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:194)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at com.hilton.sso.webservice.ClsPortalSecurityServiceStub.sessionGetValue(ClsPortalSecurityServiceStub.java:3273)
    at com.hilton.sso.CustomHiltonSSO.customValidate(CustomHiltonSSO.java:486)
    at com.hilton.sso.CustomHiltonSSO.handlesAuthenticationRequest(CustomHiltonSSO.java:354)
    at com.microstrategy.web.app.beans.WebAppSessionManagerImpl$LoginFirstContainer.createLoginFirstSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.app.beans.WebAppSessionManagerImpl.getProjectsList(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.app.beans.WebAppSessionManagerImpl.getProjectsList(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.app.beans.ServletEventHandlerImpl.setupProjectsList(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.app.beans.ServletEventHandlerImpl.createPage(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.app.beans.ServletEventHandlerImpl.createPage(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.app.beans.ServletEventHandlerImpl.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.app.beans.ServletEventHandlerImpl.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.beans.GenericEventHandler.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.app.beans.ServletEventHandlerImpl.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.beans.AbstractWebComponent.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.controller.GenericWebAppController.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.servlets.MainServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Comment: add the server SSL certificate to your client keystore. If you have access to the server, check if https is enabled in axis.xml too. IIRC by default is disabled.

Comment: When you say client keystore, are you referring to the machine which is invoking the web application? So I would install it on my laptop? The web service is being called from a web application on tomcat, so I would assume thats where the cert needs to be installed which it is.

Comment: Exactly, if the call is done from the tomcat server, you need to add the certificate to tomcat's keystore.

Comment: I believe the certificate is added to the keystore. There is verbose SSL logging enabled on tomcat, and it doesnt seem to throw any error messages. I figured it would be throwing an error related to SSL from java if that was the problem :/

Comment: then ask the web service's publisher if it has SSL enabled. (Pls add also the SSL debug if you have it)

Comment: SSL is enabled on the web service, as the code functions against the WS in another environment

Comment: Apparently the certificate in the 'working' environment was expired. Sounds fishy.